# Não consigo colocar elemento dentro de JSON

Tags: php, json

Eu tenho esse JSON `["{\"clube\":[\"Flamengo\"]}"]`, e quando executo esse código:

```
$clubes = '["{\"clube\":[\"Flamengo\"]}"]';
$clubes = json_decode($clubes, true);
array_push($clubes->clube, 'Santos');
return $clubes;
```

Tenho como retorno esse erro

```
Attempt to modify property of non-object
```

Eu queria deixar o JSON desta forma `["{\"clube\":[\"Flamengo\", "Santos"]}"]`

Comment: Você converteu clubes para array e usou notação de objeto dentro do array_push, tente `array_push($clubes['clube'], 'Santos');`

Comment: É o que o @RafaelAcioly disse mesmo. Você não pode acessar `$clubes->clube`, porque você quer acessar uma posição de um *array* e não a propriedade de um objeto.

Comment: De onde está vindo esse json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você converteu clubes para array e usou notação de **objeto** dentro do **array_push**.

```
$str = '{ "clube":["Flamengo"] }';

$tempArray = json_decode($str, true);
array_push($tempArray['clube'], 'Santos');

print_r($tempArray);
```

Comment: Usa a explicação do @RafaelAcioly na sua resposta, acho que vai ficar mais claro pro OP o que deu errado e sua resposta vai ficar mais interessante.

Comment: O problema é que já vem do servidor com os `[]` em volta, eu uso essa forma para pegar do servidor `Socios::where('socio', $socio)->pluck('clube');`, e essa para salvar `$clubes['clube'][0] = $clube;`.

Comment: Então experimenta tirar o **[0]** de $clubes['clube'][0] = $clube;

Comment: Lá dentro do banco de dados salva certo `{"clube":["Santos"]}`, mas quando eu chamo que ele vem `[ 
{"clube":["Santos"]}]`.

Comment: Olha só o que acontece, https://ideone.com/3oazhI por isso que você não consegue adicionar item

Comment: Mas como eu posso resolver, fazendo o método pegar o campo sem os `[]` ??

Comment: Laravel eu ainda sou leigo, mas você já tentou tirar **[0]** ? Se não tenta deixar assim $clubes['clube'][0] = $clube[0]

Comment: È que na verdade `$clubes['clube'][0] = $clube;` eu uso para salvar no banco de dados, e ele salva perfeitamente `{"clube":["Santos"]}`, porem na hora de retirar do banco que vem com os `[]`, ms de qualquer forma sua resposta está certa, vou pesquisar para arrumar isso, obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63697/discussion-between-wellingthon-m-de-souza-and-lucas-carezia).

Answer (score 0):

O segundo parâmetro da função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) define se o `json` sera mantido como `objeto` ou convertido para `array`, como você passou `true` então foi definido que ele seria usado como `array`, porém na linha:

```
array_push($clubes->clube, 'Santos');
```

Você esta usando a notação de `objeto` ao inves de `array`:

```
array_push($clubes['clube'], 'Santos');
```